# Hiding named ranges in Excel using a combo box and VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, named-ranges

I have inserted a combo box with 3 named ranges showing detailed data and 3 options in the dropdown ('A', 'B', 'C').
I would like to write a macro to assign to the combo box so that if the user selects 'A' from the dropdown, my named range called 'NR1' is visible whilst my other two named ranges 'NR2' and 'NR3'  are hidden. Then if 'B' is selected, 'NR1' and 'NR3' named ranges are hidden. Then if 'C' is selected, 'NR1' and 'NR2' named ranges are hidden.
The VBA is as follows but I get an error message saying 'Object required'.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If ComboBox1.Value = "A" Then
        Range("NR1").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Range("NR2").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Range("NR3").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "B" Then
        Range("NR2").EntireRow.Hidden = False 
        Range("NR1").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Range("NR3").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "C" Then
        Range("NR3").EntireRow.Hidden = False 
        Range("NR1").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Range("NR2").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot have a named range `NR1`,`NR2`,...  They are already taken by cell references.

Comment: Thanks, it’s unfortunate if I cannot use named ranges. Do you think there is another way to rewrite this code perhaps to achieve the same goal? I just need to hide some named ranges when (rows) when  I select an item from the drop down box.

Comment: How did you name a range NR1?

Comment: Apologies, in my real code I used different names for the named ranges and each named range that I used is made up of two words joined by an underscore, if that’s what you’re asking? For confidentially reasons, I used dummy names on here such as NR1, NR2 and NR3.

Comment: are they worksheet or workbook scope?

Comment: They are for just one worksheet

Comment: Then you need to append the Range{"") with the worksheet: `Worksheet("blahblah").Range("Nr1")` and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Soctt Craner, NR1...NR3 are cell names within the worksheet. Rename the ranges such as Nrng1, Nrng2, Nrng3. I've tested your code with a combobox inserted on the sheet and it is all fine.